# How to adapt Ion Auth (CodeIgniter authentication) for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I need to adapt Ion Auth (http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) for AngularJS.
Is there any tutorial about that on the internet (I can't find any).